# Are Oracle Continuous Query Notifications limited for use with Java clients only?

Tags: java, oracle

see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/continuos-query-notification.html#GUID-17D0D7C5-77C9-420D-9D13-F668C1056792

The documentation defines use for JDBC, does this mean that other Oracle drivers will not work?

If it does work on a particular version of Oracle please specify (presumably after 11g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, although the feature documentation page only mentions JDBC, it's also possible for other languages.

see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featChange.htm#ODPNT413

Also logically, JDBC must communicate over the network to the Oracle database server, and therefore it's feasible to implement for the client libraries of other software languages and not technically limited to just Java and .Net Framework.